# Continuous data and add row when no data BIGQUERY

Tags: sql, google-apps-script, google-bigquery

Pardon my English

I have data like this `[RAW Data][1]g` and I am trying to do 2 things

1. Every "data" has a,b,c,d so when ever there is no a,b,c,d we will add it and add value 0
2. Trying to make new column which sum continuous BUT calculated each code 0

If you could help I would really appreciate it; thank you guys.

I was trying many pieces of code I could find. But only continuous I can but unfortunately it is global continuous not continuous per code 2

```
SELECT tanggal,code, code2, data,

  SUM(data) OVER (ORDER BY DateT, Code 
                      ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING 
                      AND CURRENT ROW) AS ContinousData



from`market-maker-328312.MarketMakerV2.MM16
```

[docs of brief](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1CTm6Bi8ZRz6rheCqL6r7Jqr-aClh7OQTCqIUTAa0mO0/edit?usp=sharing)

[Final expectation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYnp2.pn)

[RAAW](https://i.stack.imgur.com/phzqd.png)g

Comment: Please post data and code as text not images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to do something like this below

```sql
with sample as
(

select date ('2021-01-01') as tangal,'Code 1' as code1 ,'Code a' as code2, 100 as data  union all
select date ('2021-01-01') as tangal,'Code 1' as code1 ,'Code b' as code2, 101 as data  union all
select date ('2021-01-01') as tangal,'Code 1' as code1 ,'Code c' as code2, 102 as data  union all
select date ('2021-01-01') as tangal,'Code 1' as code1 ,'Code d' as code2, 103 as data  union all
select date ('2021-01-01') as tangal,'Code 2' as code1 ,'Code a' as code2, 198 as data  union all
select date ('2021-01-01') as tangal,'Code 2' as code1 ,'Code b' as code2, 10 as data  union all
select date ('2021-01-01') as tangal,'Code 2' as code1 ,'Code c' as code2, 101 as data  union all

select date ('2021-01-02') as tangal,'Code 1' as code1 ,'Code a' as code2, 102 as data  union all
select date ('2021-01-02') as tangal,'Code 1' as code1 ,'Code b' as code2, 109 as data  union all
select date ('2021-01-02') as tangal,'Code 1' as code1 ,'Code d' as code2, 108 as data  union all
select date ('2021-01-02') as tangal,'Code 2' as code1 ,'Code a' as code2, 105 as data  union all
select date ('2021-01-02') as tangal,'Code 2' as code1 ,'Code a' as code2, 10 as data  
)
,lkp_data as
(
    select  distinct sample.tangal ,sample.code1 ,code
    from sample, (
                    select 'Code a' as code UNION all
                    select 'Code b' as code UNION all
                    select 'Code c' as code UNION all
                    select 'Code d' as code
    )
)

select  ld.*,
        if(sp.data is null,0,sp.data) as data ,
        sum(if(sp.data is null,0,sp.data))over(partition by ld.tangal,ld.code1 order by ld.code) cum_sum
from lkp_data ld
left join sample sp on  
ld.tangal = sp.tangal and ld.code1 = sp.code1 and ld.code = sp.code2
```

**Output**
[image]

Comment: thank you Mr Batra. so apperently that is my mistake to arrange the scheme. but your code show me the idea to sum continous of partition. THANK YOU so much